# Will the Hall of Monuments affect Guild Wars 2 after launch?

Tags: guild-wars

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which content can I transfer from Guild Wars 1 to Guild Wars 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269/which-content-can-i-transfer-from-guild-wars-1-to-guild-wars-2)

Following on from this question, [Which content can I transfer from Guild Wars 1 to Guild Wars 2?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269/which-content-can-i-transfer-from-guild-wars-1-to-guild-wars-2)

Does anyone know if the Hall of Monuments in Guild Wars will affect Guild Wars 2 **after release**?

For example if I have 34 points now, one short of the title at 35. Can I create a GW2 character, then keep working on my points in GW; beyond the launch of Guild Wars 2 and still reap the rewards in Guild Wars 2?

Comment: @FAE even though you did answer the question with the last sentence in your answer, this question is different from the other one though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://hom.guildwars2.com/en/faq/

> Q: Will I be able to continue earning Hall of Monuments rewards in Guild Wars after Guild Wars 2 is released?
>
> A: Yes.